# Calling on methods from another model file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model

In my Invitation model I have:

```
attr_accessor :user_token

def create_user(user)
  create_user_digest
  ...
end

private
  def create_user_digest
    self.user_token  = User.new_token
    self.user_digest = User.digest(user_token)
  end
```

It generates the error:

```
undefined method `user_digest=' for #<Invitation:0x000000044c3318>
```

I have adapted the setup from the `User` model where I have a similar setup for sign up authentication that works. `user_digest` is a column in the `Invitation` table. `.new_token` and `.digest` are methods in the `User` model (see below). What could be causing the error?

```
def User.digest(string)
  cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                BCrypt::Engine.cost
  BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
end

def User.new_token
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you don't have any setter on the user_digest attribute of the Invitation model, you should add

```
attr_accessor :user_digest
```

This way this will work the same way :user_token does (Ruby will create a getter and a setter for you).

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, what I don't understand though is that in my authentication setup in the `User` model I don't need a setter for the digest, only for the token. This makes sense to me because the digest is a variable saved to a column in the database, while the token is not (just like you don't include setters for other variables in forms when they get saved to a db). So why is this different in this case? And will it still save the digest to the db if I use a setter?

Comment: Could you give us the schema of the `Invitation` model (and `User` too), I'm pretty sure that there is no column named user_digest (maybe a typo ? )

Comment: Ah, I need coffee, the cause is I forgot to migrate after adding the column